# Metadata Exchange Problem - Limit on the number of methods?

Tags: wcf, metadata, mex-bindings

I have a WCF service exposing some 34 methods. Up until today metadata exchanging using `MetadataExchangeClient` was working just fine, but suddenly I started getting the following exception:

*Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: http://localhost:1150/service.svc?wsdl=wsdl0*

The most "interesting" thing is that if I comment out some of the methods (*no matter which ones*) in the service contract so that the service exposes *less* methods I can get metadata just right. The `web.config` settings reads

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="(...)" serviceBehavior="(...)">
  <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange" />
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
    <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="(...)"><serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"></behavior>
    <serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

All names are namespace-qualified and everything works well while exposing, say, 15 methods. Whenever I try to expose more, and no matter which ones, I get that exception. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet the added methods make the message size greater than the default max. Do you have an inner exception saying "The maximum message size quota for incoming messages (65536) has been exceeded"?

If so increase your mex binding's MaxReceivedMessageSize:

```
    <services>
        <service>
            <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="mexBinding" address="mex" />
        </service>
    </services>
    <bindings>
        <wsHttpBinding>
            <binding name="mexBinding" maxReceivedMessageSize="5000000">
                <security mode="None"/>
            </binding>
        </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
```

Note that the endpoint binding is not standard "mexHttpBinding". I'm copying from a [complete example](http://www.dasblonde.net/downloads/wcf/CustomMexBinding.zip) posted on http://www.dasblonde.net.